# Which requirements should a TSP matrix fulfill in order to be solved with Hungarian method?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hamiltonian-path

I was reading about TSP problem in general & about Hungarian method in particular, and found a 6x6 matrix, where applying Hungarian method didn't give me an answer (solved by hand & checked on 2 math websites [[1]](https://math.semestr.ru/kom/index.php) [[2]](https://cbom.atozmath.com/CBOM/Assignment.aspx?q=tsh&q1=x%2C6%2C5%2C2%2C1%2C5%3B10%2Cx%2C6%2C11%2C3%2C5%3B1%2C10%2Cx%2C12%2C15%2C1%3B2%2C12%2C4%2Cx%2C5%2C6%3B7%2C8%2C3%2C5%2Cx%2C3%3B2%2C12%2C10%2C10%2C5%2Cx%60MIN%601%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%601%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%60false%60false&do=1#PrevPart)).

\begin{bmatrix}0&6&5&2&1&5\\10&0&6&11&3&5\\1&10&0&12&15&1\\2&12&4&0&5&6\\7&8&3&5&0&3\\2&12&10&10&5&0\end{bmatrix}

That's why i'm wondering, which requirements should a TSP matrix fulfill in order to be solved by Hungarian method (except having a Hamiltonian cycle).

I would be very grateful, if you could explain it to me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: TSP = Traveling Salesman Problem, you should recall it.

Comment: @JeanMarie i've recalled it, but still no ideas, why i can solve this TSP Matrix with the "branch & bound"  algorithm and not with Hungarian one.